# Assigning value to the list element in R

Tags: r, list

Suppose I have a list of elements, and I want to change one of the elements but can't directly call the list by its name (I can only construct it as a string).

```
x_1 <- list()
for (i in 1 : 5) {
   x_1[[i]] <- i
}

assign(eval(as.name(paste0("x_", 1)))[[1]], 6)
```

Using this long construction of `assign`-`eval`-`as.name`-`paste` gives the error: `"first argument is wrong"`.

How do I do it properly? And why doesn't this construction work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by constructing the assignment expression using `<-` and then using `eval(parse(text=x))`:

```
x_1 <- as.list(1:5)
eval(parse(text=paste0("x_1[[1]] <-", 123)))

x_1
## 
## [[1]]
## [1] 123
## 
## [[2]]
## [1] 2
## 
## [[3]]
## [1] 3
## 
## [[4]]
## [1] 4
## 
## [[5]]
## [1] 5
```

---

If you want to pass the index as a variable, this might be simpler:

```
eval(parse(text=sprintf('x_1[[%s]] <- %s', 1, 123)))
```

Comment: fortune 106 seems relevant.

Comment: @jbaums, Why doesn't this construction work if I want to assign dataframe?

df <- data.frame(randomize(matrix(1:32, nrow = 8, ncol = 4)))
x_1 <- list()
eval(parse(text = paste0("x_1[[1]] <-", df)))

It somehow assigns only the last column of the dataframe to  x_1[[1]] ( and x_1[[1]] becomes an array)

Comment: @artfin: you can debug your problem by executing your code from the inside out. For example, try `paste0("x_1[[1]] <-", df)`, and you'll see that the behaviour is not what you intended (I assume). You probably want `eval(parse(text = paste0("x_1[[1]] <- df")))`. But Roland's suggestion should also work. E.g. `.GlobalEnv[['x_1']][[1]] <- df`.

Answer (score 3):

I can't image a good reason why you wouldn't know the list name. So this is probably an XY problem and you should reconsider your approach.

`assign` can't work here, because it assigns objects into an environment. That's not what you are trying to do. You want subassignment into the list.

However, assuming you have some arbitrary named list, hopefully you know at least the environment containing that list. Then you can do this:

```
.GlobalEnv[[paste0("x_",1)]][[1]] <- 6
```

Comment: Nice one - @artfin, this is the way to go.

Comment: @Roland, Thanks! This is great! 
But I never said that I don't know the list name... Actually I want to apply some actions on a bunch of lists with similarly constructed names (like x_1, x_2 etc.). Thus I wanted to find a way to act on them while calling them by names being originated 'in situ'

Comment: Then these lists should be together in a list.